# I'm subsetting my dataframe but my plots are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have return data which is indexed with a DateTimeIndex as follow

```
>ES.head()

Date
2006-01-02 19:15:00   -0.000199
2006-01-02 19:20:00   -0.000199
2006-01-02 19:25:00    0.000000
2006-01-02 19:30:00   -0.000099
2006-01-02 19:35:00   -0.000099
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

When I plot the 5-minute average returns I get the following

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(ES.groupby([ES.index.hour, ES.index.minute]).mean())
ax1.set_ylabel('Return')
ax1.set_xlabel('5-minute interval')
```

[image]

When I now drop all observations between 16:00 and 17:00 and plot the image, I get the same image!?

```
mask =  ~((ES.index.hour > 16) & (ES.index.hour < 17))
ES = ES[mask]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(ES.groupby([ES.index.hour, ES.index.minute]).mean())
ax1.set_ylabel('Return')
ax1.set_xlabel('5-minute interval')
```

With this plot

[image]

I've been stuck on this issue for more than a day now because I want to remove the returns between 16:00 and 17:00 due to market opening/closing effects creating excessive returns.

Why is my dataframe not subsetting properly?

edit:

```
>ES['2007-01-03 15:30':'2007-01-03 17:30']
Date
2007-01-03 15:30:00    0.000263
2007-01-03 15:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 15:40:00   -0.000146
2007-01-03 15:45:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 15:50:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 15:55:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 16:00:00    0.000117
2007-01-03 16:05:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:10:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:20:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 16:25:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 16:30:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:40:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:45:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:50:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:55:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:00:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 17:05:00    0.000292
2007-01-03 17:10:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 17:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:20:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:25:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:30:00    0.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64

>mask =  ~((ES.index.hour > 16) & (ES.index.hour < 17))
>ES = ES[mask]

>ES['2007-01-03 15:30':'2007-01-03 17:30']
Date
2007-01-03 15:30:00    0.000263
2007-01-03 15:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 15:40:00   -0.000146
2007-01-03 15:45:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 15:50:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 15:55:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 16:00:00    0.000117
2007-01-03 16:05:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:10:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:20:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 16:25:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 16:30:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:40:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:45:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:50:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:55:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:00:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 17:05:00    0.000292
2007-01-03 17:10:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 17:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:20:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:25:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:30:00    0.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

It seems that my mask does not work, however, when I try the following the plots are still the same while the appropriate rows are removed.

```
>ES['2007-01-03 15:30':'2007-01-03 17:30']
Date
2007-01-03 15:30:00    0.000263
2007-01-03 15:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 15:40:00   -0.000146
2007-01-03 15:45:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 15:50:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 15:55:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 16:00:00    0.000117
2007-01-03 16:05:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:10:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:20:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 16:25:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 16:30:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:40:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:45:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:50:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 16:55:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:00:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 17:05:00    0.000292
2007-01-03 17:10:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 17:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:20:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:25:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:30:00    0.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
    ​
>ES = ES.drop(ES.between_time('16:00','17:00').index)

>ES['2007-01-03 15:30':'2007-01-03 17:30']
Date
2007-01-03 15:30:00    0.000263
2007-01-03 15:35:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 15:40:00   -0.000146
2007-01-03 15:45:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 15:50:00    0.000175
2007-01-03 15:55:00    0.000058
2007-01-03 17:05:00    0.000292
2007-01-03 17:10:00   -0.000175
2007-01-03 17:15:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:20:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:25:00    0.000000
2007-01-03 17:30:00    0.000000
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: are you sure that your mask has successfully removed the 16-17 hours? The plot will only return what is in the Dataframe. Can you confirm that the mask operation worked correctly?

Comment: Apart from the above comment, would you also be able to share an extended version of your df?

Comment: See 2 edits I made to the original post. It seems that the first mask didnt work while the second mask did. However. The plots are still wrong even if the mask works. @MattR

Comment: @FaCoffee made an edit to the orignal post. The structure is the same.

Comment: do ES.shape before mask, then do ES[mask].shape..  Are those numbers different?

Comment: Yes they are different. Before: (693159,), after (664976,)